# how to compile for each C language file in a folder with multiple C-language files via cmake

Tags: cmake, compilation

```
1.c
2.c
```

If i have numerous file in one folder and I want to compile with cmake file.
Can I compile like..

```
1.out
2.out
```

like this?

Comment: In principle: yes. It depends on your CMakeLists.txt which you didn't share.

Comment: Can't I just put them in one CMakeFile and make them their own executables? If I put in 100 C files, I want them to come out as 100 executables.

Comment: Sure you can do that. What problems do you encounter doing so?